# Group into Quantities of Calls per Minute

Tags: r, vector, r-factor

I have a vector in R with sorted times (00:00 up until 23:59). Each one represents one phone call made in that minute. It has 1440 levels (24*60).

```
times <- c(00:00, 00:00, 00:00, 00:01, 00:01, 23:58, 23:58, 23:59)
```

This simplified example should yield:

```
quantity <- (3,2,2,1)
```

I want to create a vector that tells me the quantity of phone calls made at each minute. This would be a vector of length 1440 that would contain the quantity of calls made at 00:00, the quantity of calls made at 00:01, ...., the quantity of calls made at 23:29.

I'm hoping that I could somehow incorporate the fact that my vector understands it has 1440 levels to create this new vector.

Thanks!

Comment: Please supply [a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data and the code you've already tried.

Comment: sounds like a job of `table`

Comment: Use `table` with `useNA='always'`

Comment: Thank you! 'table' works @ExperimenteR